# Auto Update application windows desktop using win32

Tags: windows

I am trying to auto update my current application to new application in windows desktop using win32 api . And my application is running in background. so is there any api Microsoft providing for auto updating application or is there any procedure .please help me so that i can make update my appilication in windows desktop in vs 2005 using win32 .

Thanks 
KamalBhr

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is not Win32 API nor should there be. You will have actually have to write it. :|.

If you expect frequent updates to the application, e.g., in an environment where you want to push updates without user interaction.

- on application start, spawn a copy of the the executable.
- either periodically or through user action, check if there are updates available.
- kill the process, replace the necessary files. restart the application.
- as you spawned a copy of the executable you are free to overwrite it whilst the application is running.

Alternative, download the update packet to a directory. On next application start check if there are updates to be applied.

HTH,